# R - ggplot geom_smooth facet_grid CI not showing

Tags: r, ggplot2, broom

I am having a hard time understanding why the confidence intervals are not showing with my data. When I reproduce my code on another dataset, the code seems to work fine. For example, on `mtcars`

The code is

```
mtols = mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>% do(lm0 = lm(disp ~ mpg*gear + vs, data=.)) %>% 
               augment(., lm0) %>% 
               mutate(ymin=.fitted-1.96*.se.fit, ymax=.fitted+1.96*.se.fit)
```

To generate the plot

```
mtols %>% ggplot(aes(mpg, .fitted) ) + 
  geom_smooth(data = mtols, aes(mpg, .fitted, group = gear, colour = gear, fill= gear), method="lm") +
  theme_minimal() + facet_grid(~am)
```

I get the confidence intervals.

However this doesn't work with my data. Could someone help me figure out what goes wrong here ? I would be very grateful.

I compute the `OLS` with

```
dt = new %>% group_by(day) %>% do(lm0 = lm(y ~ year*class, data=.)) %>% augment(., lm0) %>% 
  mutate(ymin=.fitted-1.96*.se.fit, ymax=.fitted+1.96*.se.fit) 

dt$year = as.numeric(as.character(dt$year))
```

The plot, (this is an example with few cases, but the results is the same with the whole dataset)

```
dt %>% ggplot(aes(year, .fitted) ) + 
  geom_smooth(data = dt, aes(year, .fitted, group = class, colour = class, fill= class), method="lm") + 
  theme_bw() + facet_grid(~day)
```

The `CI` are not showing.

[image]

Any clue what I am doing wrong here ?

Strangely, when I don't use the `facet_grid` here, the `CI` work perfectly

[image]

```
dt %>% ggplot(aes(year, .fitted) ) + 
  geom_smooth(data = dt, aes(year, .fitted, group = class, colour = class, fill= class), method="lm") + 
  theme_bw()
```

A sample of my data

```
library(broom) 
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

new = structure(list(id = structure(c(844084L, 114510L, 14070410L, 
942483L, 13190105L, 421369L, 301384L, 251789L, 11011210L, 11280408L, 
278575L, 310410L, 16260105L, 11110815L, 18260101L, 14260501L, 
10580L, 15090210L, 19140410L, 13230615L, 246511L, 20040812L, 
14260114L, 287623L, 16090620L, 20131007L, 835743L, 453390L, 395808L, 
363617L), label = "Household identifier", class = c("labelled", 
"integer")), year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2000", "2015"), class = "factor"), 
day = c("Weekend", "Weekend", "Weekend", "Weekdays", "Weekdays", 
"Weekend", "Weekdays", "Weekend", "Weekend", "Weekdays", 
"Weekend", "Weekdays", "Weekdays", "Weekend", "Weekend", 
"Weekdays", "Weekdays", "Weekend", "Weekdays", "Weekdays", 
"Weekdays", "Weekend", "Weekend", "Weekend", "Weekend", "Weekend", 
"Weekend", "Weekdays", "Weekdays", "Weekdays"), class = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Higher Managerial", 
"Lower Managerial", "Intermediate", "Manual and Routine"), class = "factor"), 
y = c(270, 730, 180, 0, 0, 290, 90, 650, 510, 0, 10, 200, 
200, 180, 0, 0, 140, 260, 110, 740, 260, 0, 390, 610, 0, 
0, 500, 0, 10, 170)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), .Names = c("id", "year", "day", "class", "y"))
```

Comment: it seems the tow diagrams are not identical which is a problem, also are you sure it is `group = class` and not `group = day`?

Comment: @MamounBenghezal no the `group` is `class`, because I want to show the effects over time of the interaction of `class*year`, by `day`. So, I want the `facet_grid` to separate the type of days. Thanks

Comment: The example produces an error. Error: `x` and `labels` must be same type

Comment: @PierreLafortune which `x` are you referring to ?

Comment: It was your first column with `Classes 'labelled', 'integer'`. But it's okay, the problem is that you need more points to see the confidence interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confidence intervals are being drawn. We can't see them because there are only two unique points for each `day`.

```
dt2 <- dt %>% filter(class == "Higher Managerial")
plot(.fitted ~ year, data=subset(dt2, day=="Weekend"))
```

[image]

The reason we see intervals without the facet is because there is a wider interval when there are four points.

[image]

When we do not break out by facet, there are enough points to have some range in the confidence. But the confidence interval of two points has no range.

```
confint(lm(.fitted ~ year, data=subset(dt2, day=="Weekdays")))
#                     2.5 %      97.5 %
#   (Intercept) 9503.333333 9503.333333
# year            -4.666667   -4.666667
```

**Edit**

Here is a version where we use the `ymin` and `ymax` that were originally calculated, and plot it with `geom_ribbon`.

```
dt %>% ggplot(aes(year, .fitted,group = class, colour = class, fill= class)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), alpha=0.2) + 
  theme_bw() + facet_grid(~day)
```

[image]

Comment: yes you are right, I only have two days observations. But theoretically I still should be able to draw the `CI` around the conditional mean. So, is it working when weekend and weekdays are together because of that ? What could be a solution ?

Comment: You are saying that it "isn't working" but it is. It is drawing the confidence intervals, they are not wide intervals.

Comment: sorry I don't get it. what do you mean by `wide` intervals. for example `ggplot(mtcars, aes(am, disp)) +geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="lm")` still draw confidence interval, even though `am` has only two points ?

Comment: I think the problems come from the fact that the `x` should be `numeric`, if you do `ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(am), disp)) +geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="lm")`. This is annoying because my variable `year` is a dummy that is categorical not numeric! and if you introduce it as numeric then the results are wrong.

Comment: that isn't the problem. In your example, there are many y-axis points for the two x-axis points. But in your question, there are two y-axis data points and two on the x-axis.

Comment: I still can't really get my head around it. What would be then the solution ? To draw barplot with CI ? This equation `confint(lm(.fitted ~ year, data=subset(dt2, day=="Weekdays")))` doesn't make sense. The CI come from the variance between the id in the different class. You can't regress a line that is already fitted. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I used that because that is what your equation is doing `geom_smooth(data = dt, aes(year, .fitted, ...`. You are plotting the year on the x-axis and .fitted on the y.

Comment: Did you know that you are running the regression twice? That might be the sticking point. The first regression is this `new %>% group_by(day) %>% do(lm0 = lm(y ~ year*class, data=.))`; and the second is inside `geom_smooth(data = dt, aes(year..`.

Comment: Maybe this is the problem. Thank you for your patience. Do you have any solution ? thanks

Comment: You might be looking for `geom_ribbon` instead of `smooth`. Because 'smooth' is calculating it's own regression line. You already did that part. 'ribbon' will allow you to use the `ymin` and `ymax` that you already created.

Comment: I added an example with `geom_ribbon` and the ymin and ymax from the data.